# Using cmder . Windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, cmder

I downloaded Cmder on my PC but I want that the cmd starts on a folder as then I can navigate because if not the cmd starts in the Cmder folder and I can't go anywhere. Can someone help me, please? Wish you understood me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont give us much to go on but you should have a shortcut with which to start cmder perhaps on your desktop something like this.

[image]

If not find your installed copy of cmder.exe then `Right Click` it then select `Send To`
and then finally select `"Desktop (as shortcut)"`

Right click the shortcut and select `Properties` of that shortcut and then add your prefered starting DIRectory after a `/start` DIRective

[image]

[image]

If you want to Autorun other start-up commands see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68185482/10802527

Answer (score 3):

Very simple and best way to get CMDER wherever you want is adding it to de Windows Context Menu (right click).

1. Open a terminal as an Administrator
2. Navigate to the directory you have placed Cmder
3. Execute `.\cmder.exe /REGISTER ALL`

If you get a message "Access Denied" ensure you are executing the command in an Administrator prompt.
In a file explorer window right click in or on a directory to see "Cmder Here" in the context menu.
From: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder#shortcut-to-open-cmder-in-a-chosen-folder
Tip: put the CMDER files in c:\Program Files\CMDER

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to change the directory you start from each time you open a new terminal.

To do that:

1. click `Win+Alt+t` to open the settings
2. In the settings group 'Startup' choose 'Tasks'
3. Choose the console you want to modify (e.g. cmd::Cmder, cmd::Cmder as Admin, etc..)
4. Click the '`Startup dir...`' button
   [image: settings screenshot]
5. Select the directory you want the console to startup in by default
6. Enjoy!